# Non-System disk or disk error, replace and strike any key when ready

Tags: windows, windows-vista, partitioning

I've installed Windows Vista again on my HP 6830S laptop, but on other partition (D:). So here were two Windows instalations (one on C (old) and one on D (new)).

I've tried to format C disk with old Windows, but without any success, so I found out that I can disable C and then format, so [i followed instructions on this MSDN forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/how-to-format-a-system-partition-created-by/27fae440-2c27-4285-8703-7f66ee128030) (see first answer by Shinmila H) and reboot.

After that I'm getting this error:

> "Non-System disk or disk error, replace and strike any key when ready"

And I can't start any Windows any more.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems to me like you erased your MBR configuration. Have you tried to repair your installation using the Vista installation disk?

Comment: I have not tried because it doesn't want to read CD/DVD past last year

Comment: Try using a Linux CD and creating a fresh MBR with `fdisk`.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the windows CD/DVD or run the recovery console.  You want to just have the recovery console command prompt.  Then you'll have to run the commands "fixmbr" and "fixboot" to make the system bootable again.